# Is there any class which gives greater width than modal-lg?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am using vue.js with Bootstrap.

There is modal dive which shows like below I am finding a class that increase the width of modal div,

My modal div looks like this. I am planning to add 12 more tabs and for that I will need more width.

[image]

I am using `modal-lg` class to set the width.

**I am using below code for modal div**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_create_product" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Create Product
                </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Form Errors -->
                <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="createForm.errors.length > 0">
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>Whoops!</strong> Something went wrong!</p>
                    <br>
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="error in createForm.errors">
                            {{ error }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no built in modal-** class that has a higher width than that. You can use your own css class and specify that like so,
@media (min-width: 992px)
#modal_create_product .modal-dialog.modal-lg {
    width: 1200px;
}

Answer (score 0):

I just do

```
.modal-lg {
      max-width: 70%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `min-width` CSS for your  `modal-content`?
Like this:

```
 .modal-dialog.modal-lg {
     min-width: 80%
 }
```